# How do I get schema / column names from parquet file?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs, parquet

I have a file stored in HDFS as `part-m-00000.gz.parquet`

I've tried to run `hdfs dfs -text dir/part-m-00000.gz.parquet` but it's compressed, so I ran `gunzip part-m-00000.gz.parquet` but it doesn't uncompress the file since it doesn't recognise the `.parquet` extension.

How do I get the schema / column names for this file?

Comment: The [Apache Arrow project](https://arrow.apache.org/) supports a variety of languages and makes it easy to get the Parquet schema with a variety of different languages.  See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You won't be able "open" the file using a hdfs dfs -text because its not a text file. Parquet files are written to disk very differently compared to text files.

And for the same matter, the Parquet project provides parquet-tools to do tasks like which you are trying to do. Open and see the schema, data, metadata etc.

Check out the parquet-tool project
[parquet-tools](https://pypi.org/project/parquet-tools/)

Also Cloudera which support and contributes heavily to Parquet, also has a nice page with examples on usage of parquet-tools. A example from that page for your use case is

```
parquet-tools schema part-m-00000.parquet
```

Checkout the Cloudera page. [Using the Parquet File Format with Impala, Hive, Pig, HBase, and MapReduce](http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_ig_parquet.html)

Comment: Thank you. Sounds like a lot more work than I expected!

Comment: Here is the [updated repository for parquet-tools](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/tree/master/parquet-tools).

Comment: None of the provided github links are working anymore :(

Comment: parquet-tools link is broken.

Comment: Updated link of the tool https://pypi.org/project/parquet-tools/

Answer (score 14):

**Parquet CLI:**
[parquet-cli](https://github.com/chhantyal/parquet-cli) is a light weight alternative to parquet-tools.

```
pip install parquet-cli          //installs via pip
parq filename.parquet            //view meta data
parq filename.parquet --schema   //view the schema
parq filename.parquet --head 10  //view top n rows
```

This tool will provide basic info about the parquet file.

**UPDATE** (Alternatives):

- If you wish to do this using a GUI tool then checkout this answer - [View Parquet data and metadata using DBeaver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74010417/6563567)
- **DuckDB** CLI

DuckDB has [CLI tool](https://duckdb.org/docs/installation/) (prebuilt binaries for linux, windows, macOS) that can be used to [query parquet data](https://duckdb.org/docs/data/parquet) from command line.

```
PS C:\Users\nsuser\dev\standalone_executable_binaries> ./duckdb
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
```

Read Parquet Schema.

```
D DESCRIBE SELECT * FROM READ_PARQUET('C:\Users\nsuser\dev\sample_files\userdata1.parquet');
OR
D SELECT * FROM PARQUET_SCHEMA('C:\Users\nsuser\dev\sample_files\userdata1.parquet');
┌───────────────────┬─────────────┬──────┬─────┬─────────┬───────┐
│    column_name    │ column_type │ null │ key │ default │ extra │
├───────────────────┼─────────────┼──────┼─────┼─────────┼───────┤
│ registration_dttm │ TIMESTAMP   │ YES  │     │         │       │
│ id                │ INTEGER     │ YES  │     │         │       │
│ first_name        │ VARCHAR     │ YES  │     │         │       │
│ salary            │ DOUBLE      │ YES  │     │         │       │
└───────────────────┴─────────────┴──────┴─────┴─────────┴───────┘
```

more on DuckDB [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74260936/6563567).

Comment: like them a lot better than the parquet-tools

Comment: parquet-tools threw an error about a missing footer, but parquet-cli worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

If your Parquet files are located in HDFS or S3 like me, you can try something like the following:

HDFS

```
parquet-tools schema hdfs://<YOUR_NAME_NODE_IP>:8020/<YOUR_FILE_PATH>/<YOUR_FILE>.parquet
```

S3

```
parquet-tools schema s3://<YOUR_BUCKET_PATH>/<YOUR_FILE>.parquet
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 6):

If you use Docker you can also run parquet-tools in a container:

```
docker run -ti -v C:\file.parquet:/tmp/file.parquet nathanhowell/parquet-tools schema /tmp/file.parquet
```

Comment: best way to run them

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's capable to use a desktop application to view [Parquet](https://parquet.apache.org/) and also other binary format data like [ORC](https://orc.apache.org/) and [AVRO](https://avro.apache.org/). It's pure Java application so that can be run at Linux, Mac and also Windows. Please check [Bigdata File Viewer](https://github.com/Eugene-Mark/bigdata-file-viewer) for details.

It supports complex data type like array, map, etc.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[Apache Arrow](https://arrow.apache.org/) makes it easy to get the Parquet metadata with a lot of different languages including C, C++, Rust, Go, Java, JavaScript, etc.

Here's how to get the schema with PyArrow (the Python Apache Arrow API):

```py
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

table = pq.read_table(path)
table.schema # pa.schema([pa.field("movie", "string", False), pa.field("release_year", "int64", True)])
```

See [here](https://mungingdata.com/pyarrow/parquet-metadata-min-max-statistics/) for more details about how to read metadata information from Parquet files with PyArrow.

You can also grab the schema of a Parquet file with Spark.

```scala
val df = spark.read.parquet('some_dir/')
df.schema // returns a StructType
```

StructType objects look like this:

```
StructType(
  StructField(number,IntegerType,true),
  StructField(word,StringType,true)
)
```

From the StructType object, you can infer the column name, data type, and nullable property that's in the Parquet metadata.  The Spark approach isn't as clean as the Arrow approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using R, the following wrapper function on functions existed in **arrow** library will work for you:

```
read_parquet_schema <- function (file, col_select = NULL, as_data_frame = TRUE, props = ParquetArrowReaderProperties$create(), 
                                 ...) 
{
  require(arrow)
  reader <- ParquetFileReader$create(file, props = props, ...)
  schema <- reader$GetSchema()
  names <- names(schema)
  return(names)
}
```

Example:

```
arrow::write_parquet(iris,"iris.parquet")
read_parquet_schema("iris.parquet")
[1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not a text file, you cannot do a "-text" on it.
You can read it easily through Hive even if you do not have the parquet-tools installed, if you can load that file to a Hive table.

Comment: Thank you. I wish - my current environment doesn't have hive, so I just have pig & hdfs for MR.

Comment: unless you know parquet column structure you will not be able to make HIVE table on top of it.