# How does BigQuery read the schema of a parquet file that is in Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I ask because I'm getting an error while loading a BigQuery table from parquet files that makes me think it's reading the mode of some fields incorrectly.

I'm attempting to load a parquet file from parquet to bigQuery from cloudShell:

```
loc1=gs://our-data/thisTable/model=firstmodel

bq --location=US load --noreplace --source_format=PARQUET our-data:theSchema.theTable $loc1/*.parquet ./ourSchema.json
```

There are ~30 parquet files in the directory referenced in loc1.
I get an error that points to one of those specific files:

```
    BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job 'our-data:bqjob_re73397ea395b9fd_0000016ae66ab746_1': Error while reading
data, error message: Provided schema is not compatible with the file 'part-00000-20b9e343-460b-44a8-b083-4437284d6771.c000.snappy.parquet'.
Field 'dataend' is specified as NULLABLE in provided schema which does not match REQUIRED as specified in the file.
```

However when I access the parquet file through spark and run printSchema(), the field comes up as NULLABLE:

> root  |-- row_id: long (nullable = true)  |-- row_name: string
>   (nullable = true)  |-- dataend: string (nullable = true)

and the schema on the BigQuery table is NULLABLE, as is the appropriate section of the schema JSON:

[image]

I'd appreciate any help knowing where to look next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Spark SQL writes parquet files it [automatically converts](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/sql-programming-guide.html#parquet-files) all columns to NULLABLE for compatibility reasons.

You can inspect the parquet file itself using [parquet-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36140264/inspect-parquet-from-command-line/54961957#54961957) to double check if REQUIRED is set in the original file.