# How to export BigQuery table to parquet using SQL and keep columns mode

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, parquet

I'm trying to export BQ table to GCS in the parquet format. Can't use API because of the size limits, so it's gotta be SQL query. The problem is when using SQL query, parquet ignores table columns mode.
So when I create table like this

```
CREATE or replace TABLE sandbox.newtable (x INT64, y STRING, z BOOL NOT NULL, d DATE)
partition by d
  OPTIONS(
    description = 'My example table')
   as select 1 ,'s', false, current_date()
```

and it's exported using query below

```
EXPORT DATA  
  OPTIONS ( 
    uri = 'gs://path/*.parquet', 
    format = 'PARQUET', 
    compression = 'SNAPPY') 
AS (
  SELECT x,y,z,d FROM sandbox.newtable  
);
```

z column changes its mode to nullable (and I can't overwrite the column mode on the load as Parquet stores schema inside the file). Is there any way to export it using SQL and keep the correct modes?

Comment: You mean that you lost the "not null" constraint when you perform the export, correct?

Comment: yes. Field is changed to nullable, when it should be required and it creates all sorts of issues.

Comment: Not expert in Parquet format. I saw similar issue with Azure Synapse and export to Parquet. Are you sure that not null constraint is possible in Parquet? Is there any limitation by using it? (I saw the nulls are not in the Data part but in the descriptor.)

Comment: yes, I'm sure. When data is exported directly from the BQ using BQ API everything is fine. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#python But export using SQL causing problems.

Comment: I think it's a limitation/side effect. You should use the table export. If it's too big shard your table and extract it piece by piece... Not funny, but I don't see any option to change the current behavior...

Comment: This makes sense. My problem is 50tb per project. I have workaround for now, but would love to hear from Google folks

Comment: null ness is not kept through queries.  Just a note buying pipeline reservations (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#export_jobs) removes the 50TB constraint

Answer (score 0):

I found a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56282685/how-does-bigquery-read-the-schema-of-a-parquet-file-that-is-in-google-cloud-stor) that potentially answers your question. The [shared article](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/sql-programming-guide.html#parquet-files) in the answer says:

> When writing Parquet files, all columns are automatically converted to be nullable for compatibility reasons.