# Translating BigQuery Repeated data type to parquet

Tags: java, google-bigquery, apache-beam, parquet

I have a BigQuery table with a REPEATED field made up of structured data (RECORD) made up of just two keys: KEY and VALUE. It would look like this:

```
[{"KEY":"TESTING_FLAG", "VALUE": "TRUE"},{"KEY":"THRESHOLD", "VALUE": "10"}]
```

In BigQuery the schema looks like this:
[image]

I wrote an Apache Beam java job that should had handled the equivalent field by writing it to GCS as parquet, and built an external table on top of the parquet files. However the schema came out looking like this:
[image]

I'm concerned this might not faithfully represent the same data type we had originally in the native BigQuery table. We passed to the Beam job an avro schema that defined the field as:

```
{
      "name": "DS_GUARDRAILS",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "record",
            "name": "DS_GUARDRAIL",
            "fields": [
              {
                "name": "KEY",
                "type": "string"
              },
              {
                "name": "VALUE",
                "type": "string"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "default": null
    },
```

Should I have done this differently to mimic the original structure? Or is this just quirk of BigQuery of representing parquet data of this type through an external table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your later assumption is correct, this is just the way BigQuery represents the data, but it doesn't mean that the data is altered. The difference you are seeing is due to Parquet's storage optimization as it internally flattens nested structures compared to BigQuery which explicitly has a nested structure.

Adding in related resources you can reference.

- [Loading Parquet data from Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-parquet)
- [How does BigQuery read the schema of a parquet file that is in Google Cloud Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56282685/how-does-bigquery-read-the-schema-of-a-parquet-file-that-is-in-google-cloud-stor)
- [Inspect Parquet from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36140264/inspect-parquet-from-command-line/54961957#54961957)

Answer (score 1):

The avro schema you posted technically provides an extra degree of freedom then the original BigQuery schema.  BigQuery does not allow storage of null lists.  Removing nullability in the beam avro schema would I guess make the two  align (not super familiar with Beam though).

Another option that could work for schema alignment is to override the parquet sink's parquet-mr value for [WRITE_OLD_LIST_STRUCTURE](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-avro/src/main/java/org/apache/parquet/avro/AvroWriteSupport.java#L70) and use set [enable_list_inference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#external_table_option_list) on the external table

Comment: Hi Micah, happy new year, thank you for your reply. When you say "remove the nullability", the schema would look like this?

{
      "name": "DS_GUARDRAILS",
      "type": [
        {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "record",
            "name": "DS_GUARDRAIL",
            "fields": [
              {
                "name": "KEY",
                "type": "string"
              },
              {
                "name": "VALUE",
                "type": "string"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }

Comment: Happy new year, yes that avro schema looks like what I was suggesting

Comment: Im not sure it could work for our use case, because that field can be nullable though. Do you know another way to bypass the issue?

Comment: Sorry I missed the nullability of key-value values.  If those the field you want to remain nullable then you will want something like: `[ { "name": "KEY", "type": ["null", "string"] }, { "name": "VALUE", "type": "[null, string]" } ]` to keep that property.  If the list itself becomes nullable (and not just an empty list) the new schema produced is the only way to model this in BigQuery currently.  If the distinction between a null list and an empty list is not important for user of BigQuery the second suggestion in my answer about changing WRITE_OLD_LIST_STRUCTURE might also be applicable)

Comment: Hey Micah, thanks again for helping with this. I wanted to let you know that I tried that and it didnt work, so I wanted to leave a trace for anybody else who might run into the same issue (it generated a second nested layer); Ill update my post above tomorrow with pictures. I will try one more time with the WRITE_OLD_LIST_STRUCTURE and see where that lands us and ill let you know how it goes.