# Inspect Parquet in S3 from Command Line

Tags: amazon-s3, parquet

I can download a single snappy.parquet partition file with:

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket/my-data.parquet/my-data-0000.snappy.parquet ./my-data-0000.snappy.parquet
```

And then use:

```
parquet-tools head my-data-0000.snappy.parquet
parquet-tools schema my-data-0000.snappy.parquet
parquet-tools meta my-data-0000.snappy.parquet
```

But I'd rather not download the file, and I'd rather not have to specify a particular snappy.parquet file. Instead the prefix: "s3://bucket/my-data.parquet"

Also what if the schema is different in different row groups across different partition files?

Following instructions [here](https://confusedcoders.com/data-engineering/hadoop/how-to-view-content-of-parquet-files-on-s3hdfs-from-hadoop-cluster-using-parquet-tools) I downloaded a jar file and ran

```
hadoop jar parquet-tools-1.9.0.jar schema s3://bucket/my-data.parquet/
```

But this resulted in error: No FileSystem for schema "s3".

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47288395/5289570) seems promising, but only for reading from HDFS. Any solution for S3?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote the tool [clidb](https://github.com/dannyboland/clidb) to help with this kind of "quick peek at a parquet file in S3" task.

You should be able to do:

```sh
pip install "clidb[extras]"
clidb s3://bucket/
```

and then click to load parquet files as views to inspect and run SQL against.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this aws cli command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/select-object-content.html), it works for files larger than 128 MB as opposed to S3 Select in AWS Console.
You need to specify the file directly though. For different schemas in row groups you will need a more robust solution but to me that is outside of scope for a "quick peek".

```
aws s3api select-object-content \
--bucket bucket \
--key "my-data.parquet/my-data-0000.snappy.parquet" \
--expression "select * from s3object limit 100" \
--expression-type 'SQL' \
--input-serialization '{"Parquet": {}, "CompressionType": "NONE"}' \
--output-serialization '{"JSON": {}}' "output.json"
```

The command will create `output.json` file with the output.

Answer (score 0):

I found this pip installable [parquet-tools](https://pypi.org/project/parquet-tools/) which gives you info about the parquet files on S3. The only pre-req is that you should have access to the files on S3.

```
parquet-tools inspect s3://path/to/file.parquet
```