# How can i get the schema details(table structure) from parquet file using hdfs API

Tags: api, hadoop, hive, parquet, webhdfs

I have a parquet file located in hdfs system. I am using webhdfs API to read file but not getting the schema details in proper format.

Any help would be appriciated?

Comment: You may take advantage from [How do I get schema column names from Parquet file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33883640/) or [Inspect Parquet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36140264/).

Comment: Hi but this has command line interface. i have to write  a java code to execute webhdfs api in read mode and get schema details. Actually i tried but API response is not in correct format.

Is there any way that we can get schema details from parquet file using java code from hdfs location?

Comment: Maybe reviewing `parquet-tools` source (Java) can help? https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/tree/parquet-1.11.x/parquet-tools

Comment: but parquet-tools available for unix system but how can i execute these query in window using java code?